# Associated Values of a view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UILabel` and need to reference its initial indexPath.row in another view controller? I have already used the tag of the UILabel for a different purpose, but is there a way I can set an associated value of some sort with the UILabel in swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UILabel should not be acting as a store for data, that's what data structures are for. One simple possibility to start out with is to have the tag be the index of that label's data in an array or use the tag value as the key of a dictionary and store the data you need in those data structures.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom view for your TableViewCell (which I assume you are ), I would just create new custom view (inherited from UILabel) and add another property to it for indexPath and assign this property with the original indexPath, I would use this custom label view instead of UILabel.  Please let me know if you have questions about this approach.

Comment: I'm new to iOS, so how would I make it inherited from uiLabel?

Comment: Yes.  There is no problem with inheriting from UILabel, if you do need to use the additional field.  You get all the functionality of UILabel with the additional property to use for your special purpose.

Comment: I understand the functionality of it, but how would I make it inherited from the uiLabel.

Comment: Go to File --> New File in XCode, Create a new Cocoa touch class - name it customLabel or whatever and make it subclass of UILabel

Comment: Alright, got it. Thanks wasn't sure what you meant.